# Webpack-dev-server — HMR Not receive update signal from WDS

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, hot-module-replacement

HMR Not receive update signal from WDS

- Operating System: MacOS 10.12.6
- Node Version: 8.5.0
- NPM Version: 5.3.0
- webpack Version: 3.6.0
- webpack-dev-server Version: 2.8.2

#### Code

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true,
    inline: true
  },
  entry: {
    main: [
      './test/main.js'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '__[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ],
        exclude: /\/(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'Hot Module Replacement'
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
}



// ./test/main.js

console.log('Test')
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept()
}
```

#### Terminal output

```
webpack-dev-server  

Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from ./dist
Hash: 07cd69bf3e44cc2f62fe
Version: webpack 3.6.0
Time: 990ms
        Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    __main.js     357 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
__main.js.map     425 kB       0  [emitted]         main
   index.html  193 bytes          [emitted]         
  [36] ./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
  [37] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./test/main.js 52 bytes {0} [built]
  [38] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 7.27 kB {0} [built]
  [39] (webpack)/node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
  [45] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
  [47] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 7.74 kB {0} [built]
  [48] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.04 kB {0} [built]
  [80] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.71 kB {0} [built]
  [81] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/ansi-html/index.js 4.26 kB {0} [built]
  [85] (webpack)/hot nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]
  [87] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
  [88] ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js 1.61 kB {0} [built]
  [89] ./node_modules/webpack/hot/log-apply-result.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
  [90] ./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
  [91] ./test/main.js 62 bytes {0} [built]
    + 77 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
       [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/default_index.ejs 538 bytes {0} [built]
       [1] ./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js 540 kB {0} [built]
       [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
       [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

#### Generated html on http://localhost:8080/ by HtmlWebpackPlugin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Hot Module Replacement</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="__main.js"></script></body>
 </html>
```

#### Chrome Console

```
log.js:23 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
main.js:1 >>>
client:77 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

Then change `main.js` — `console.log('>>>>')` to `console.log('Changed')`

#### Chrome Console after changed main.js

```
log.js:23 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
main.js:1 >>>
client:77 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
client:80 [WDS] App updated. Recompiling...
client:213 [WDS] App hot update...
```

Comment: How did you resolve this? I also experience this issue while trying to access it from external device which is a OSX

Comment: workaround on this time, run webpack-dev-server locally: ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js

also update issues on https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1110

Answer (score 3):

I try your config on Ubuntu via Docker:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty
- Docker: 17.06.2-ce, build cec0b72
- Node image: 8.5.0

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

### Configuration
RUN mkdir -p /code
COPY ./webpack.config.js /code

### Requirements
RUN npm install -g webpack-dev-server@2.8.2
RUN npm install babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-env
RUN npm install html-webpack-plugin
RUN npm install webpack@3.6.0

### Application
WORKDIR /code
EXPOSE 8080
```

All works fine:

[image]

I think your problem in MacOS environment.
I hope my answer help you find problem.